# long list set of numbers

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a list of sets and some of the sets have almost 1000 elements and some have 14 elements. At the moment I use `\\` and `&` to separate the lines but somehow it doesn't look proper. Some lines appears to be longer than the other. Is it possible to like separate them in lines automatically and justify them so that all the length are the same.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{align*}
R=&[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,22,23,24,25, 27, 28,29]\\
S=&[4, 5, 11, 16, 18, 19, 23, 24, 26, 31, 33, 37, 41, 44, 48, 49, 50, 53, 54, 60, 66, 67, 68, 74, 77, 78, 79,\\
& 80, 81, 82, 85, 87, 88, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 100, 102, 103, 104, 107, 109, 110, 111, 114, 115, 117, 119,\\
& 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 133, 138, 139, 141, 142, 145, 146, 147, 151, 152, 155, 158, 161, 163, 164,\\
& 165, 169, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 178, 180, 181, 183, 184, 185, 187, 189, 195, 196, 197, 198, 200, 201,]
\end{align*}
```

If you run the command you will see that 79, 119, 164, 201 are the end of the line but are not alligned.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to automatically wrap you have to specify a line width; in the macro I propose, the width is 80% of the current line width, but can be adjusted with the optional argument, as shown in the `T` line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\numberlist}[2][0.8\linewidth]{%
  [\parbox[t]{#1}{\printcommalist{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\printcommalist}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`,\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathcomma\penalty0 }%
  \mathcode`,="8000
  \thinmuskip=6mu plus 6mu minus 2mu
  $#1]$
}
\mathchardef\mathcomma=\mathcode`,

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
R&=[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,22,23,24,25, 27, 28,29]\\
S&=\numberlist{
  4, 5, 11, 16, 18, 19, 23, 24, 26, 31, 33, 37, 41, 44, 48, 49,
  50, 53, 54, 60, 66, 67, 68, 74, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87,
  88, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 100, 102, 103, 104, 107, 109, 110, 111,
  114, 115, 117, 119, 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 133, 138, 139, 141,
  142, 145, 146, 147, 151, 152, 155, 158, 161, 163, 164, 165, 169,
  171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 178, 180, 181, 183, 184, 185, 187, 189,
  195, 196, 197, 198, 200, 201
}\\
T&=\numberlist[.6\linewidth]{
  4, 5, 11, 16, 18, 19, 23, 24, 26, 31, 33, 37, 41, 44, 48, 49,
  50, 53, 54, 60, 66, 67, 68, 74, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87,
  88, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 100, 102, 103, 104, 107, 109, 110, 111,
  114, 115, 117, 119, 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 133, 138, 139, 141,
  142, 145, 146, 147, 151, 152, 155, 158, 161, 163, 164, 165, 169,
  171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 178, 180, 181, 183, 184, 185, 187, 189,
  195, 196, 197, 198, 200, 201
}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a more informal look, with ragged lines, just change the line

```
\thinmuskip=6mu plus 6mu minus 2mu
```

into

```
\raggedright
```

that would give

[image]

A different implementation that allows the lists to break across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newenvironment{numberlists}[1][3\parindent]
 {\begin{list}{}{%
   \leftmargin=#1\relax
   \rightmargin=\leftmargin
   \itemsep=\jot
   \parsep=0pt
   \partopsep=0pt
   \labelsep=0pt}}
 {\end{list}}

\newcommand\numlist[2]{%
  \item[]\makebox[0pt][r]{$#1=\lbrack$}%
  \begingroup
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`,\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathcomma\penalty0 }%
  \mathcode`,="8000
  \thinmuskip=6mu plus 6mu minus 2mu
  $#2\rbrack$%
  \endgroup
}

\mathchardef\mathcomma=\mathcode`,

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2-6]
\begin{numberlists}
\numlist{R}{0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,22,23,24,25, 27, 28,29}

\numlist{S}{
  4, 5, 11, 16, 18, 19, 23, 24, 26, 31, 33, 37, 41, 44, 48, 49,
  50, 53, 54, 60, 66, 67, 68, 74, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87,
  88, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 100, 102, 103, 104, 107, 109, 110, 111,
  114, 115, 117, 119, 120, 122, 123, 124, 125, 133, 138, 139, 141,
  142, 145, 146, 147, 151, 152, 155, 158, 161, 163, 164, 165, 169,
  171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 178, 180, 181, 183, 184, 185, 187, 189,
  195, 196, 197, 198, 200, 201
}
\end{numberlists}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It really helped a lot. But then I wonder why it does not break into pages. Because supposedly the list of sets takes up to 4 pages. But now everything is compressed into one page passing through the page number till the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Sharina Breaking across pages is quite a different thing. I added a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @egreg ! Thi has been of a great help. Just a quick question. Which command should I change if I require more elements per row. For example all the elements in R goes in a row instead of 2.

Comment: @Sharina You can call `\begin{numberlists}[1cm]` to make the margins equal to 1cm (the label sticks in the left margin).