# How to display a longish sequence of lists of numbers?

Tags: lists

I have to show some long vector transformation such as this one --- see image below.  You begin with the vector on the left and a transformation takes it to the vector on the right.  (See image below.)

This presentation easily gives me underfull problems.  **Can you suggest some way of displaying such vector sequences better?**  The vector notation is not required.  You can think of these numbers as lists.

I wouldn't like to use patterns and the power of ``...'' because I think the exposition won't be as clear as if the reader sees the whole thing straightforwardly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$$\begin{bmatrix}0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
  0,1767\\0,1767\end{bmatrix}
\to 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,15467\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\end{bmatrix}$$ 

\end{document}
```

Check how vertical it gets and how much space is wasted.  If no better idea comes up, I'll probably try [something like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269027).

[image: My attempt at showing the transformation]

Comment: Please do not misinterpret this comment, but I am really wondering: who will, in the year 2019, really *read* these numbers? Wouldn't it be better to just describe what these vectors are good for and provide the numbers/lists in some downloadable format somewhere such that anybody who wants to play with them can get them?

Comment: You could break the vector into blocks and display the blocks using align with lots of &s.

Comment: @marmot, I think you're a bit out of context.  These numbers are the amplitudes of vectors in quantum mechanics:  0,1767 is 1/sqrt(32).  In the proper context, you can follow easily what happens to them as they go through some quantum transformations.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I'm not quite sure I see your idea.  I think you mean instead of a one vertical list, using align to perhaps displaying 4 vertical lines of 8 numbers each.  That's a neat idea!  That might do just fine.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can certainly typeset whatever you like. Frankly, all information I can see is that there are two vectors of equal dimensions, one of which is filled by 1/(4*sqrt(2)) and the other one by two different numbers, `X` and `Y`, that come in a pattern 3 times `X` followed by 3 times `Y` followed by three times `X` and so on, and there is one place where there is an additional digit. Just for the records, I would illustrate this differently. But this is just a comment, and not an instruction or something like this.

Comment: Whatever else you end up doing, I suggest you load the `icomma` package, so that the spacing around the `,` (comma) characters is appropriate for their use as decimal markers. (By default, TeX's math mode inserts some space after the commas.)

Comment: `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
When dealing with positions on a higher--dimensional
lattice, some use exponents to denote the repeating entries of the lattice
 vectors, so 
\[ (0^3\,1^2\,0^2\,1)~\equiv~(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1)\;.\]
In this notation, your equation may be condensed to 
\[ \bigl(z^{32}\bigr)~\to~\bigl(x^2\,(y^3\,x^3)^5\bigr)\;,\quad
\text{where}~z=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\;,~x=-0{,}1546\;,~~y=0{,}1988\;.\]
\end{document}` is my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split in half:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{topmatrix}{\left\lceil\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right\rceil}
\newenvironment{botmatrix}{\left\lfloor\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right\rfloor}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\[
\begin{topmatrix}
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
\end{topmatrix}
\to
\begin{topmatrix}
-0,1546\\-0,1546\\ 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\
 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\ 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\
\end{topmatrix}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{botmatrix}
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
\end{botmatrix}
\to
\begin{botmatrix}
 0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\ 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\-0,1546\\
-0,1546\\-0,15467\\0,1988\\ 0,1988\\ 0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\
\end{botmatrix}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This is probably the nicest solution I could get given my circumstances.

Comment: @JoepAwinita With a `midmatrix` using `\left|` and `\right|` you could also split into three.

Comment: I see.  I get the idea.  Very nice solution indeed.  Very grateful for the idea.  (I'm also seeing the `\makeatletter` for the first time.  Cool stuff.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use wrapfig.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
  0,1767\\0,1767\end{bmatrix}
\to 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,15467\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{minipage}\end{wrapfigure}
\sloppy
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

---

With `flalign*` I could squeeze in 3 blocks, but they were too close together to be easily distinguished.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767
\end{bmatrix}
&\to 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\0,1988\\
 0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\
0,1988\\0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\
-0,1546\\-0,1546\\0,1988\\0,1988
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\
0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767\\0,1767
\end{bmatrix}
&\to 
\begin{bmatrix}
0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\
0,1988\\0,1988\\0,1988\\-0,1546\\
-0,1546\\-0,15467\\0,1988\\ 0,1988\\
0,1988\\-0,1546\\-0,1546\\-0,1546
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat, but I think your first idea might work better due to my context here.  Nearby pages contain a lot of equations and wrapping equation-text on the left of these numbers will probably be a bit confusing.  I'll try this one too, but I believe I'll stick to your first idea.

Comment: After ;your comment I decided to add that one as well.  (It was more work.)

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that (a) the numbers don't have to be typeset as column vectors and (b) you wish to save some space; I assume you wish to typeset several numbers per line. You could place the numbers in `minipage` environments, choosing the widths so that 3, 4, 5, or even 6 numbers could be typeset in each row. (The following example typesets 4 numbers per line.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{icomma} % treat "," as decimal marker (no extra space)
\newlength\lena
\newlength\lenb
\begin{document}

\settowidth\lena{$0,0000$ }
\settowidth\lenb{$-0,0000$ }

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{4\lena}
\raggedright
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ 
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ 
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ 
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ 
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ 
$0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$ $0,1767$
\end{minipage}
\qquad$\to$\qquad
\begin{minipage}{4\lenb}
\raggedright
$-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ $0,1988$ $0,1988$ 
 $0,1988$ $-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ 
 $0,1988$ $0,1988$ $0,1988$ $-0,1546$ 
$-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ $0,1988$ $0,1988$ 
$0,1988$ $-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ 
$0,1988$ $0,1988$ $0,1988$ $-0,1546$ 
$-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ $0,1988$ $0,1988$ 
$0,1988$ $-0,1546$ $-0,1546$ $-0,1546$
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```